# Magento SOAP WSDL JAVA - create product

Tags: java, api, magento, soap, wsdl

I'm new using magento api, so I generate the classes using Eclipse.

> create -> new -> other -> WebService client / put de magento api wsdl.

then Eclipse creates for me the classes.

I can list all catalog_products.list using the api.

But I dont know how to create a product using the api "catalog_product.create"

I am following this docummentation to create a product but there's only example in PHP.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.create.html

here's my code.

```
public void consumirWebService() throws Exception {
        BindingStub service = (BindingStub) new MagentoServiceLocator().getPort();
        String token = service.login("user", "password");
        Map<String, String>[] mapss = new Map[1];
        Map<String, String> mapProduto = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapProduto.put("type", "virtual");
        mapProduto.put("sessionId", "1");
        mapProduto.put("set", "4");
        mapProduto.put("sku", "7622300243449");
        mapProduto.put("storeView", "1");
        mapProduto.put("name", "NOME PRODUTO");
        mapProduto.put("description", "descricao");
        mapProduto.put("short_description", "short description");
        mapProduto.put("weight", "1");
        mapProduto.put("status", "1");
        mapProduto.put("price", "100");
        mapProduto.put("visibility", "4");
        mapProduto.put("tax_class_id", "1");
        mapProduto.put("website_ids", "1");
        mapProduto.put("categories_ids", "1");
        mapss[0] = mapProduto;
        Object o = service.call(token, "catalog_product.create", mapss);
        System.out.println("ID" + o);
    }
```

i get this exception always :

> Invalid data given. Details in error message.

Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0):

The example should be enough to understand how you create something with a SOAP Client. The names of the methods and classes are all the same , only different langauge. Try to find the equivalent of each inside your generated java classes.